# How to autoplay storyboard animation on page load using Expression Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, expression-blend, storyboard

I've got a storyboard that should play when a page loads. Is there any way to do that directly from Expression Blend? I'd rather not do it through code or xaml.

What about doing the same for button clicks or other events?

Thanks

Comment: The Behavior answer below is by far the easiest.  I certainly understand your aversion to dong this in code, but just for clarity sake let me say this: if you are doing it "from Blend" then you ARE doing it "in XAML".  Blend is just writing the XAML for you. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can drag the ControlStoryboardAction behaviour (Assets->Behaviors) over to the Page, and set the *EventName* to be PageLoaded, and *ControlStoryboardOption* to Play, and *Storyboard* to your storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to do this via code then all you need to do is just to call Begin() of the StoryBoard. Like for example:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeIn">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="img"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0"
                         To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>


private void btnFadeIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.fadeIn.Begin();
}
```